# Do'nt set LayoutParams LayoutInflater

Tags: android-layout, android

i use LayoutInflater to create dynamically ui with xml files but resualt is not suitable.
like inflater not set layout params?
my sample code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.linearlayoutdef, null);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageviewdef, null);
    iv.setImageBitmap(op.getImage());

    TextView tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.textviewdef, null);
    //tv.setText(op.getType().toString());
    tv.setText("Call");

    Button be = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttondef, null);
    be.setText("Edit");
    Button bd = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttondef, null);
    bd.setText("Delete");

    ll.addView(iv);
    ll.addView(tv);
    ll.addView(be);
    ll.addView(bd);
```

my sample xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/linearLayout" >
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="linearLayout" >
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">40pt</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3pt</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3pt</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     style="@style/imageViewStyle" android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
     android:src="@drawable/stop"
     >
</ImageView>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="imageViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_width">30pt</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">30pt</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3pt</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/imageview_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke android:width="0.9pt" android:color="#808080"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

witch result is:

[image]

but right result must be :

[image]

what can i do to get right result?

Comment: why don't you make all the widgets in same layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set layout params to each view you add to your view group.

Example :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
view.setParams(params);
```